# ttyUSB device problem (cp210x ttyUSB1: failed to set baud rate to 300)

Tags: xilinx

I've been trying to transfer data from my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04) to the [Xilinx VCU110 evaluation board](http://xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/dk-u1-vcu110-g.html), but it's not working. I did catch this message, which could shed some light on the issue:

```
$ dmesg | grep ttyUSB
cp210x ttyUSB1: failed to set baud rate to 300
```

Comment: What exactly is "the FPGA board"?

Comment: Field-Programmable Gate Array, which is specified using a Hardware Description Language (HDL).

Comment: I meant which model board is it.

Comment: Xilinx VCU110 evaluation board (https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/dk-u1-vcu110-g.html)

Comment: Do you still have this problem? If you receive an answer here that solves your problem please accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer. In this way you can help others with the same issue find answers that work. If you don't receive an answer that solves your problem please [edit] your post to indicate what happened when you tried the answers provided so that we can further assist you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the approach. On page 132 of the documentation available from the link you provided in your comment It states quite plainly:

```
set baud rate to 115200, data to 8 bit, parity to none, stop to 1 bit, and flow control to none
```

Matching the settings to what the board supports would seem prudent.

Source:

https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/vcu110/ug1073-vcu110-eval-bd.pdf